# Unable to prepare input file for HSPF software for watershed modeling!

Tags: hydrology, software, watershed

I am trying to use BASINS 4.1 software to prepare input file for HSPF (.uci). When I launch HSPF from BASINS software, I have to direct the sofware to read a time series file (.wdm). In my case I am unable to tell the sofware to do this because the 'met stations' tab is not providing me the option to do this. I am having complete blank 'met stations' tab. Anyone has any ideo how to fix this problem? Or is there any other way to prepare input file for HSPF (.uci file) without using BASINS?[image]

Answer (score 2):

I have found the solution and it seems that in BASINS 4.1, user has to import wdm file before launching HSPF by going to 'File' and then to either 'import data' or 'manage data'.  Once this step is done, BASINS 'understands' that there is a wdm file and then the user can add the wdm file from 'met stations' tab. 
The tutorials on epa site correspond to BASINS 4.0 and in BASINS 4.0, one doesn't have to go through the so call 'import data' step before launching HSPF.